# React Native - How to deal with asynchronism with AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage, asynchronous-javascript

I am facing to asynchronism problem :

1. I create a user in firebase, generating a unique ID for it.
2. I get this unique ID.
3. I call an async function to persist this ID with AsyncStorage method.

Problem : The asyncStorage method is called before I get back the generated ID from my user creation. How to deal with this ?

This is my code :

```
class Subscription extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '', 
      password: ''
    }
  }

  persistUserId = (userID) => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', userID); // Here, user ID is undefined
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  updateInputValue = (value, prop) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[prop] = value;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  registerUser = () => {
    var generatedUserId = '';

    firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password) // Authentication
    .then((res) => {
        var user = { // Set Javascript Object to insert
        email: this.state.email
        }

        database.collection("users").add({ // Create the new user generating an ID
            'email': user.email,
        }).then(function(docRef) {
            generatedUserId = docRef.id; // Get the generated ID (The one to persist witch asyncstorage)
        }).then(function() {
            this.persistUserId(generatedUserId) // Call the AsyncStorage to persist the ID
        })
            this.props.navigation.navigate('AppPage') // Go to next page.
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert(error.message)
    })      
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For persisting data. According to react-native doc. You need to use **async await** keyword:

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      '@MySuperStore:key',
      'I like to save it.'
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
}
```

for your case:

```
persistUserId = async (userID) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', userID); // Here, user ID is undefined
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

**Note:** Persisting data is async process. That's why you need to use async await

You need to update your firebase then catch as well. Either use **bind** or use **arrow** function. Here is updated version:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password) // Authentication
  .then((res) => {
    var user = {
      // Set Javascript Object to insert
      email: this.state.email,
    };

    database
      .collection("users")
      .add({
        // Create the new user generating an ID
        email: user.email,
      })
      .then( (docRef) =>  {
        generatedUserId = docRef.id; // Get the generated ID (The one to persist witch asyncstorage)
      })
      .then( () =>  {
        this.persistUserId(generatedUserId); // Call the AsyncStorage to persist the ID
      });
    this.props.navigation.navigate("AppPage"); // Go to next page.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error.message);
  });
```

Comment: I get this error : Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.persistUserId).

Comment: Not sure.  Check with your error object. There are high chances there is no **message** field in it

Comment: I check it without the "try catch", same error. It's like the method persistUserId is never launched...

Comment: Ahh its because you are using function. So it is not getting this in scope. Better way is to wrap in arrow function

Comment: Let me know if you still dont understand will update that code as well

Comment: Wow, this is tricky ! Tanks a lot ! You made my day !!